# How do I prove this equality about sums?

Tags: real-analysis, statistics, summation

The equality is given by

$$\frac{1}{(T-1)}\sum\limits_{j=1}^T \sum\limits_{i: i < j}\frac{1}{T}(x_i-x_j)^2=\frac{1}{(T-1)}\sum\limits_{j=1}^T (x_j-\bar{x}_n)^2$$

EDIT: $\sum\limits_{i: i < j}=\sum\limits_{i=1}^{j-1}$ and $\bar{x}_n$ denotes the sample mean

Comment: Is $n$ the same as $T$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume that $T=n$.

Let $\displaystyle S_x=\sum_{j=1}^n x_j$ and  $\displaystyle S_x^2=\sum_{j=1}^n x_j^2$.

Note that the mean is $\displaystyle\overline{x}=\frac 1n\sum_{i=1}^n x_i$, i.e. $S_x=n\overline{x}$.

$$\begin{align}
\sum_{j=1}^n \big(x_j-\overline{x}\big)^2
&=\sum_{j=1}^n \big(x_j^2-2\overline{x}x_j+\overline{x}^2\big)\\
&=S_x^2-2\overline{x}\underbrace{S_x}_{n\overline{x}}+n\overline{x}^2\\
&=S_x^2-n\overline{x}^2\tag{1}\\\\
\frac 1n\sum_{j=1}^n\sum_{i=1}^{j-1} \big(x_i-x_j\big)^2
&=\frac 1n\cdot \frac 12\bigg[\sum_{j=1}^n\sum_{i=1}^n (x_i-x_j)^2-\overbrace{\sum_{i=j}(x_i-x_j)}^0\bigg]\\
&=\frac 1{2n}\sum_{j=1}^n\sum_{i=1}^n\big(x_i^2-2x_ix_j+x_j\big)\\
&=\frac 1{2n}\big(nS_x^2-2S_x\cdot S_x+nS_x^2\big)\\
&=\frac 1{2n}\big(2nS_x^2-2n^2\overline{x}^2\big)\\
&=S_x^2-n\overline{x}^2\tag{2}
\end{align}$$

Hence $(1)=(2)$.

Dividing both by $(n-1)$ gives $\text{RHS}=\text{LHS}.\;\blacksquare$